# Angular 2+ Currency Mask

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, currency-formatting

I tried a couple of the currency masks out there for Angular 2+ but my requirements don't really fit them so I'm trying to create a Directive myself. Here's what I need:

1. Allow for null values. Keep the value as a number, not a string.
2. On Focus remove currency format. On blur re-format.
3. Enter number from right to left (so for $250.00 the user would have to type [2] -> 5 -> 0. (so not starting from the decimal point)
4. Don't allow users to type anything but numbers and decimal separator.
5. Text-align right

I got most of this working.

**The only issue is that it only works on focus/blur/keypress. Since the data is loaded async for my components, no event in the directive is triggered so the initial load of existing dollar amounts isn't formatted.** Here's my Directive so far:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyMaskService } from './currency-mask.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCurrencyMask]'
})
export class CurrencyMaskDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private currencyMaskService: CurrencyMaskService) {
    this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.style.textAlign = 'right';
  }

  // On Focus remove all non-digit or decimal separator values
  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onfocus(value) {
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.parse(value);
  }

  // On Blur remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.transform(value);
  }

  // On Blur remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
  onChange(value) {
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.transform(value);
  }

  // Prevent user to enter anything but digits and decimal separator
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event) {
    const key = event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
    if (key !== 46 && key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reddit r/Angular2 community was able to help me find the answer: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/82oojo/angular_2_currency_mask/

I was completely missing on how to keep track of the value itself, by using the ControlValueAccessor I was able to accomplish what I wanted. See code below:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyMaskService } from './currency-mask.service';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyMaskDirective),
  multi: true
};

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCurrencyMask]',
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CurrencyMaskDirective implements AfterViewInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  private innerValue: any = 0;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private currencyMaskService: CurrencyMaskService) {
    this.el = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  // Placeholders for the callbacks which are later providesd
  // by the Control Value Accessor
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  private onChangeCallback: (a: any) => void = noop;

  // set getter
  get value(): any {
    return this.innerValue;
  }

  // set accessor including call the onchange callback
  set value(v: any) {
    if (v !== this.innerValue) {
      this.innerValue = v;
      this.onChangeCallback(v);
    }
  }

  // Set touched on blur
  // onBlur() {
  //   this.onTouchedCallback();
  // }

  // From ControlValueAccessor interface
  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.innerValue) {
      this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.transform(value);
      this.innerValue = value;
    }
  }

  // From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  // From ControlValueAccessor interface
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.el.style.textAlign = 'right';
  }

  // On Focus remove all non-digit or decimal separator values
  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onfocus(value) {
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.parse(value);
  }

  // On Blue remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.onTouchedCallback();
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.transform(value);
    this.onChangeCallback(this.currencyMaskService.parse(this.el.value));
  }

  // On Change remove all symbols except last . and set to currency format
  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value'])
  onChange(value) {
    this.el.value = this.currencyMaskService.transform(value);
    this.onChangeCallback(this.currencyMaskService.parse(this.el.value));
  }

  // Prevent user to enter anything but digits and decimal separator
  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyPress(event) {
    const key = event.which || event.keyCode || 0;
    if (key !== 46 && key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

*EDIT:
Here's the full code I ended up using: https://github.com/LeoTanoue/ngx-currency-mask