# Angular currency mask

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular, and I've followed the [Angular 2+ Currency Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139595/angular-2-currency-mask) to get currency getting typed from left to right. But I have a requirement of a maximum value on this, which means the user will not be able to enter a value more than that.

Can this be modified to handle that condition?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but don't.

Set your validator for the formControl to have a maximum value:

```
value: ['', [
  Validators.required, 
  Validators.max(42)
]];
```

Don't use Pipes, like currency, to do anything but transform a value.

Comment: I have this in a dialog which is not part of form control. Is there any other way we can do it?

Comment: You need to post some code to better explain what you're trying to do. I'm not certain of your objective as you've described it.

Comment: Assuming you have an input in the dialog, you can use the native HTML5 validator on the `<input>` tag. Like so:

<input type="number" min="1" max="5">